# Can I use cocoa-dusted coffee in my moka pot?

Tags: espresso, moka

I have a 3-cup Bialetti Moka Express pot and some coffee beans dusted with cocoa powder that I bought from a chocolate shop. My French press is stuck at work due to the quarantine, so I can't use them up the way I have been. I also have a Chemex carafe and set of filters, but I fear that the Chemex filters will take out all of the cocoa powder, defeating the purpose of the beans.

I have tried using these beans in my moka pot twice at this point. Both times resulted in the pot sputtering a lot and brewing very slowly, rather than filling the reservoir in a quick burst like it does with regular coffee. My first attempt it was extremely slow, but I chalked that up to a too-fine grind playing badly with the extra difficulty of cocoa powder. My second attempt used a coarser grind, and it seemed to brew more quickly, but the top of the moka pot was not at the usual level it is when I use plain coffee.

Will using cocoa-powdered coffee in my moka pot cause any permanent damage to the internal workings, or do I just need to make sure I wash all the cocoa powder out between uses?

Answer (score 1):

If the cocoa powder is ground up cocoa bean withou added sugar/milk etc. I can't see any issue.

If it contains sugar, it will leave some residue in the machine wich I imagine might get hard to get out if it builds up.